# Clear inputs after adding to list

Tags: angularjs

I have the following HTML in an AngularJS application:

```
  <form name="form" ng-submit="vm.save(vm.data)">  
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="d in vm.data.degrees">
        <td ng-bind="d.school"></td>  
        <td ng-bind="d.field"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div>
      <input id="school" type="text" ng-model="d.school"/>
      <input id="field" type="text" ng-model="d.field"/>
      <button class="button" type="button" ng-click="vm.addDegree(d.school, d.field)">
        Add Degree
      </button>
    </div>       
    <input id="name" type="text" ng-model="vm.data.name"/>
    <button>Submit form</button>
  </button>        
</form>
```

I have a button which adds a degree (`d.school` + `d.field`) to the list (`table`).
When I add an item to the list I want to clear the inputs `school` and `degree`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reset `d.school` and `d.degree` in the `ng-click` directive like this :

```
ng-click="vm.addDegree(d.school, d.field);d.school = '';d.degree=''"
```

You can take a look at [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Z70q6BnE8M7iFtc1Dbtw?p=preview)

Comment: Even better: d=null;